# html form submits prematurely on validation subroutine using jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, html, form-submit, dialog

I am using the jquery dialog box to display messages during form completion. All but the last dialog box seem to work. The last one displays briefly, but the "X" does not appear, the box dismisses automatically, and the form is submitted prematurely.

Sample of the incomplete dialog box is here:
http://www.bbhq.com/dbox.htm

(The form must submit before the "X" image has time to display.)

I am using jquery-1.10.1.

I think it might be a jquery issue. When I replace the jquery dialog box with a simple "alert," it works.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
  function valdata() {
    alert ("watch closely; dialog box will pop up; dismiss automatically; and form will submit")
      $("<div title='Basic dialog onclick'>made simple b4 submit</div>").dialog();
  return
```

here is the html:

```
  <FORM NAME="mainform" METHOD="POST" ACTION="http://www.bbhq.com/dummy.htm"
      onSubmit="return valdata()"  >

      <a href="#" onclick="alertok('see, it works here')">test dialog box here</a><p>

  1. this is question 1.
    <input type=text name=ques1><p>
  2. this is question 1.
    <input type=text name=ques2><p>
  3. this is question 1.
      <input type=text name=ques3><p>


  <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="  Click here to submit the form   ">

  </FORM>
```

In the onSubmit code, I have tried it with and without a "return."

I tried removing the onsubmit, and replacing the input submit with a button which calls the function and then submits the form. The result was the same.

My sample is here: http://www.bbhq.com/tmp-form.htm 
(Sorry; I could not make jsfiddle work for me.)

I am a newbie with jquery, but I have designed dozens of forms. Am I missing something obvious here?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

instead of having an onsubmit attribute on the form add this to your page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form[name="mainform"]').submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();

       valdata();
       return false;
    });
});
```

What it does:

1) wait for the dom to load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

2) bind a submit handler to the form:

```
$('form[name="mainform"]').submit(function(e) {
```

3) stop the default browser behavior from occuring (ie: following the attribute action on the form

```
e.preventDefault();
```

4) stop the event from bubbling up the call stack

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

5) call your function

```
valdata();
```

6) return false to prevent form from submitting (return true to allow the form to submit)

```
return false;
```